# i have a problem with displaying my question in seperate page in react

Tags: reactjs

i am doing a quiz app in react in which i want to display one question in one page but in my case all the question are displayed in a single page,how will i do that?

i am using a react version 16.8 i have used my main component as state component and other component as functional component.

i did my code in codesandbox i will add a link so that you people can see it

codesandboxlink:https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-bush-7rmpu

i expect that one question and its suitable option should be displayed in one page and if i click the next button it the question should toggle to next question if i click previous button it should toggle to previous question

Comment: Your codesandbox link is broken with it's dependencies.

Comment: i have changed can you check now

Comment: You are adding all the questions on same page using `map`. You need some external packages to do your job like - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-quiz-component

Comment: This can also be useful - https://material-ui.com/components/steppers/

Comment: cant we do anything with this method?

Comment: but how do i add my looped ques into state ?

Answer (score 1):

Almost your problem is importing issues. Correct it like below:

In `index.js` file, update:

```js
import React from "react";
import Previous from "./Previous/Previous";
import "./styles.css";

// class App extends Component
// You need to use React.Component here
class App extends React.Component {
//..
```

---

In `Next.js` and `Previous.js` files

```js
import "../styles.css"; // Not found "../App.css"
```

Comment: i have changed can you check now

Comment: Please correct `import ... "./previous/Previous"` into `import ... "./Previous/Previous` in `index.js` file

Comment: Your problem is folder name import `./previous/Previous`

Comment: what yu want me to add

Answer (score 1):

I've updated the sandbox now:

You could do something like this and update a current_index and hide the other questions with CSS so they still remember your answer (if you don't save it with javascript ofc):

https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-cache-io72h

Hope it helps.

Comment: Then you should mark the solution as correct. And I don't know why I got a downvote.

Comment: I didn't do anything actually I don't have enough reputation to upvote and downvote